# How do I optimize MariaDB query with subqueries in FROM clause?

Tags: subquery, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

imagine these two tables.

Table A

```
ID col1 col2 col3
1  foo  baz  bar
2  ofo  zba  rba
3  oof  abz  abr
```

Table B

```
A_ID field_name field_value
1    first      Jon
1    last       Doe
2    first      Adam
2    last       Smith
```

etc..

Now I would like to have a query (current one looks like this)

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.col1, 
    a.col2, 
    (SELECT field_value FROM B WHERE A_ID = a.id AND field_name = 'first') as first_name, 
    (SELECT field_value FROM B WHERE A_ID = a.id AND field_name = 'last') as last_name
FROM A a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE A_ID = a.id) = 2;
```

This query is working. What I would like to achieve would be something like this.

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.col1,
  a.col2,
  (SELECT field_value FROM b WHERE b.field_name = 'first') as first_name,
  (SELECT field_value FROM b WHERE b.field_name = 'last') as last_name
FROM
  A a,
  (SELECT field_value, field_name FROM B WHERE A_ID = a.id) b
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b) = 2;
```

How would my approach look correctly? Is there any other way to get rid of the multiple queries of the table B?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the ugly world of EAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace your correlated subqueries with joins:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.col1, 
    a.col2,
    b1.field_value AS fv1,
    b2.field_value AS fv2
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b1
    ON a.id = b1.A_ID AND b1.field_name = 'first'
LEFT JOIN B b2
    ON a.id = b2.A_ID AND b2.field_name = 'last';
```

This answer assumes that a left join from a given A record would only match at most one record in the B table, which, however, is a requirement anyway for your correlated subqueries to only return a single value.

Comment: First of all thank you. Secondly sorry for questioning your answer, but what benefit do I have from it? Is it faster? Or just because of readability?

Comment: The join approach should outperform your current approach, especially as the tables get larger.

Comment: You are right. I am aproximately 20% faster with the joins. Thank you!

Comment: We can make it even faster, potentially, through indexing, and the original approach would be harder to optimize.